# I need a daily automated deployment in my mobile device using Xamarin Forms Trial version

Tags: deployment, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working in a new app (for concept tests) and I would like to get the application in my tablet for a week in order to review that with some partners and get their comments. The Xamarin Trial only let you use the apk for 24hs, this is the reason I would like to automate the build day by day.

Using:
Xamarin Forms (last release)
By now: Deployment for Android

Does Someone have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could build a release of the app with a [build server](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/teamcity/#Compiling_Android_Applications) like TeamCity(any other will do) and drop the apk on a location you can reach with you device. Then you only need to install the app.

Or you could write a build script calling the [build and install](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/#Build_Targets) targets.

Comment: ok, you are right. I will install TC on my local and let you know. Thanks

Comment: This is probably the closest answer to what you're after. Otherwise you could create a cron job/service which runs a script to generate the .apk and install it to your device as mentioned in his second link.

Comment: Yes this could be another solution, but I can not install the generated apk (debug and neither release folder). I only can get the app installed on my device if I plug it as debugger in VStudio